# How to prevent GDB from stepping into every single function

Tags: debugging, gdb

My GDB debugger automatically steps into most functions (particularly my external libraries, the standard library). This is quite annoying since I know those libraries are way better written than my code.
How is it possible to prevent GDB from doing that?

Comment: what do you mean by `gdb debugger automatically steps into most functions`?

Comment: When I typed 'continue', gdb used to go the next line. But now (since i use Linux), it steps into any function even if it's from an external library. For instance, when debugging `string str = "foo";` gdb steps into functions in `string.h`.

Comment: `continue` doesn't go to the next line, `next` does. You're probably doing `step` instead of `next`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `next`

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to get what you want.

One is to use `next` rather than `step`.  `step` will step into a function call, but `next` will step over it.  Choosing the stepping command you want to use next is by far the most common way to deal with this issue.

Now, this isn't always exactly what you want.  In particular, you might be on a line that has a number of calls on it, and there is some subset of the calls that you always want to skip over.  This is typical in C++, where there are often many tiny accessors and trivial constructors that are essentially uninteresting -- but you must nevertheless laboriously step through each one to get into the call you do care about.

For this more complicated scenario, GDB has the `skip` command.  This can be used to "blacklist" certain functions (or entire files).  When a function is blacklisted, `step` will not step into it.  See the manual for more details on how to use `skip`.

One final very heavy way to achieve the same effect is to make sure that you do not have any debug information for libraries that you don't want to debug. GDB will automatically not step into functions for which there is no debug information.