# How to skip over unnecessary functions/files while debugging VSCode in Linux/g++/gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I have the following code (`Main.cpp`) in VSCode on ubuntu and debugging using gdb:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string return_string(){//Line 4
        std::string abc = "abc";
        return(abc);
}
    
int main(){//Line 9
        std::string abc = return_string();//Line 10
        std::cout<<abc<<std::endl;//Line 11
        return 0;
}
```

With breakpoint hit on Line 10, hitting F10 in the hopes of getting to Line 11 instead takes me inside `basic_string.h` file that is a C++ file not part of my project. Is there a way to not enter into such native C/C++ files? I have looked at:

[How to prevent GDB from stepping into every single function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752228/how-to-prevent-gdb-from-stepping-into-every-single-function)

but that seems to talk about working with gdb raw and suggests specifying the `skip` command (https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html) inside gdb. I, however, run the debugger via VSCode interface that provides an encapsulation layer over gdb without having the user to use raw gdb commands -- `F10` steps over, `F11` steps into and so on.

Is there a way to prevent certain files from being entered into while debugging via stepping through the code while compiling and linking itself? Currently, my makefile issues the following commands for compiling and linking:

```
(compiling) g++ -fno-common -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fopenmp -c -g -std=c++14 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/1/Main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/1/Main.o ../src/Main.cpp 
(linking) g++ -fno-common -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fopenmp -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/linux build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/1/Main.o -lm -lpthread -ldl
```

Comment: Learn the difference between stepping **in** and stepping **over**. It's likely you've got your keyboard shortcuts mixed up.

Comment: `basic_string.h` is entered into on pressing F10 (stepping over) when breakpoint is hit on Line 10. Is that expected? Can that be avoided?

Comment: I'd you were actually stepping over, it wouldn't do that.

Comment: I just tried on Windows and gdb behaves as expected, step over on line 10 goes to line 11

Comment: @sweenish consider standard containers and function wrappers that call client code after a long series of indirections through dense standard library code, such as `std::make_unique` and `std::function`

Comment: @alterigel No need, stepping over always works as expected. The issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: @rioV8 Could you please try `std::string abc;` then on next line `abc = return_string();` ?

Comment: no real big difference, a normal step-over

Answer (score 0):

Like someone else said, I think you meant F11 (step into) when you said F10 (step over).  You already have most of the answer -- the `skip` command of gdb.  (This is referred to as "NoStepInto" in the MS Visual Studio world.) The missing piece is that you likely want these commands to be executed automatically when running your IDE.  To do that, create and edit a `~/.gdbinit` file in your user home directory.  Add a line to add a "safe" path to another `.gdbinit` file, this one in your project's executable folder:

`add-auto-load-safe-path /home/your_username/your_project/your_bin_dir/.gdbinit`

Then edit the project-specific `.gdbinit` file you just referenced, and add the commands you want automatically executed, one per line.  For example, this `.gdbinit` skips over anything inside the `std` namespace when you perform "step into:"

`skip -rfunction ^std::.*`

The `-rfunction` option specifies a regular expression, but there are other ways to specify functions to skip; see the gdb documentation.